# rtf change font size

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to perform edit functions in a RichTextBox on a C# (Windows Forms) application.
I would like to be able to select any number of text characters in the script then change targeted font characteristics.
The trouble I have is that each characters font properties  may be set to different font. In this case the textbox ignores the event that I request.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to that problem either, so I had to scan the selection one character at a time to find chunks with all the same font properties and change the size of each of those chunks. So I'm hoping that better answers emerge here!

Comment: See [Changing font for richtextbox without losing formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16307021/719186)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
[Changing font for richtextbox without losing formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306184/changing-font-for-richtextbox-without-losing-formatting)

I think it's the same issue. LarsTech's solution is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score -2):

I have a code to change the size:

```
RichTextBox1.Font.Size == new System.Drawing.Font(RichTextBox1.Font.Name, yoursize)
```

And if you want to change only the selected text size:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Size == new System.Drawing.Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Name, yoursize)
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Control Size is not equatable to a Font.

Comment: Sorry, I meant RichTextBox1.Font.Size == new System.Drawing.Font(RichTextBox1.Font.Name, yoursize)