# Change RichTextBox Font keeping text color

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, richtextbox, rtf

I have a lot of formatted code snippets saved in an XML file. 
On request I load them and set as Rtf in a RichTextBox:

```
string cscode = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq1\fcharset0 Courier New;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0..." etc.
rtb_cs.Rtf = cscode;
```

The code snippets are copy-pasted from the Visual Studio, so the text is colored differently.
Different Visual Studios are using different Fonts for the text.

**Is there a way to change the Font but keep the colors?**

I've tried to set the `Font` property of the RichTextBox, but this also resets the colors.

```
//This changes colors as well
rtb_cs.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LarsTech's solution here:

[Changing font for richtextbox without losing formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306184/changing-font-for-richtextbox-without-losing-formatting)

It works for other settings too.

Comment: I've seen that and it looks complicated. I thought maybe there is a more simple way to achieve that

Comment: If your only problem is the color, you can get the color of the text and then set the ForeColor porperty again after changing font.

Comment: the problem is that the the text has different colors, just like in Visual studio, comments are green, strings are red etc. so I can't set the Forecolor for the whole rtf. Maybe I have to check every character, note it's color and then restore it again

Comment: The solution I gave isn't too complicated. Just add a class, paste the given code. Edit the designer file and replace the type "RichTextBox" with the new one "RichBox".

Comment: Thank's Jerry, I know how it works, but still, I've expected the more simple way. I just found a simple workaround, will edit my question later with solution.