# How to Read and modify Hindi .rtf file programmatically?

Tags: c#, filestream, rtf

I have a hindi RTF file with content like:

> कोलकाता, 11 दिसंबर  पश्चिम बंगाल के बर्दवान जिले में कक्षा नौ की एक छात्रा ने फांसी लगाकर आत्महत्या कर ली।

In my console application I want to read that RTF file and Change some content programatically.

I using streamreader to read the file but when converting to string it is producing the following output:

> ÚUæCþUèØ-SßæS‰Ø
>
> ×Âý Ñ Sßæ§Ù Üê •¤è ¼ßæ ÂØæü# ×æ˜æ ×ð´ ãUôÙð •¤æ ¼æßæ
>
> ÖæðÂæÜ, vv ç¼â¢ÕÚ (¥æ§ü°°Ù°â)Ð ×ŠØ Âý¼ðàæ ×ð´ Sßæ§Ù Üê ¥æñÚ ÇðU¢»ê âð ¥Õ Ì•¤ •¤§ü Üæð»æð´ •¤è ×æñÌ ãUæð ¿é•¤è ãñU ¥õÚU ¥SÂÌæÜ ×ð´ ç¿ç•¤ˆâ•¤èØ âéçßÏæ¥ô´ •¤è •¤×è •ð¤ âæÍ-âæÍ ¼ßæ¥ô´ •ð¤ ¥Öæß •ð¤ Öè ¥æÚUæðÂ Ü»Ìð ÚãðU ãñU¢Ð
>
> SßæS‰Ø çßÖæ» Ùð ãUæÜæ¢ç•¤ ØãU ¼æßæ ç•¤Øæ ãñU ç•¤ Úæ…Ø ×ð´ ×æñâ×è ÚUæð», Sßæ§Ù Üê •ð¤ ©Â¿æÚ •ð¤ çÜ° Âý¼ðàæ •ð¤ ¥SÂÌæÜæð´ ×ð´ ¥æßàØ•¤ ¼ßæ¥æð´ •¤æ ÂØæü# ÂýÕ¢Ï ç•¤Øæ »Øæ ãñUÐ

I have tried the windows form RichTextBox to read the RTF file, but it always show Invalid File Format.

So what will be the best possible solution to read and modify rtf file in C#

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fpath, Encoding.Default, true);
string s1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

also tried

```
using (System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox())
{
    // Get the contents of the RTF file. Note that when it is 
    // stored in the string, it is encoded as UTF-16. 
    string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fpath);

    // Convert the RTF to plain text.
    rtBox.Rtf = s; // error file format invalid
    string plainText = rtBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Specifing encoding is probably best solution.

Comment: I have tried all the encodings supported by C#.net

Comment: But you didn't tried to show what you tried.

Comment: Try to trim any '\r' or '\n' at the beginning and the ending.

Comment: Hindi is a unicode only locale, bets are the file is saved as either UTF-8 or UTF-16

Comment: You loading data to rtf control incorrectly. Use LoadFile as @kennyzx mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The `RichTextBox` control can [load an RTF file directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7.aspx), do not use `StreamReader` to read RTF file because it can contain a lot of `Control Characters`.

After loading the file to the `RichTextBox`, use the `Text` property to get the plain text of the file.

`RichTextBox` also has a `SaveFile` method to save the modified content to a file.

Comment: i have already used the richtextbox. See the code i posted. It gives error file format invalid. Even loadfile method is giving the same error.

Comment: Can you open it in MS Word?

Comment: MS word is not the proper way for server. In my local system the rtf file is opened in MS but produce the above same result like

Comment: same result like ×ÙæðÚ¢U…æÙ-çâÙð×æ
¥×ðçÚU•¤è ÙõâðÙæ âð ×éÜæ•¤æÌ •¤ÚU »¼»¼ ãéU§ZU ç•¤×
Üæòâ °¢…æðçÜâ, x ç¼âÕÚU (¥æ§üU°°Ù°â)Ð çÚU°çÜÅUè ÅUèßè SÅUæÚU ç•¤× •¤¼æüçàæØæ¢ •¤ãUÌè ãñ´U ç•¤ çÂÀÜð ×ãUèÙð âõÖæ‚Ø âð ©U‹ãð´U ¥×ðçÚ•¤è ÙõâðÙæ âð ×éÜæ•¤æÌ •¤æ ×õ•¤æ ç×ÜæÐ
 and when i select the Chanayka Font it shows the text in Hindi

Comment: What about `rtb.SelectAll(); rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Chanayka",...);`, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16306184/815938)?

Comment: when rtb is blank what is use of SelectAll(). I have to put first the tring and then select all. Plz. show the way.